# Parse the values from Parent Node XML Response

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have following XML Structure response.

```
     <informationDetails>
     <info>
        <age>
           <age>24</age>
       </age>
    </info>
     <info>
        <age>
           <age>23</age>
       </age>
    </info>
    </informationDetails>

In javascript,

  var InfoTag = response.getelemntstagbyname("age")[0].textcontent.trim();
```

If I pass 0 or 1 I can get 24 . If I pass 2 or 3 I can get 23.

But I need to to get the values like if i pass 0 i need to get 24.If I pass 1 I need to get 23.May be the root cause is parent and child has the same tag names?

How can I change the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.firstElementChild` chained to `.getElementsByTagName` to reference first element child of parent `<age>` element

```
response.getElementsByTagName("age")[0].firstElementChild.textContent.trim()
```

You can alternatively use `.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"age > age"`

```
response.querySelectorAll("age > age")[1].textContent.trim()
```